# Installed joomla 2.5 template not working true

Tags: templates, content-management-system, joomla2.5

sorry for my english.
I'm new for joomla,after i install new template on joomla 2.5 and set it for default template,when i review my site,template not working true.for example menus,sliders,headers,footers not visible.
Thank for you'r attentions.

Comment: That is not really a question. But I will try: Which template, is it a 2.5 template (why don't you use 3.x as it is the actual release?). Did you clear the cache? Is it using JS and JS is blocked? Any information in the logs? These are questions ;-)

Comment: no,not a problem with these,tnx.